# NextJS и проксирование через Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, nextjs

Всем привет. У меня есть сайт, который как фронт использует NextJS, на бекенде php (Yii2).

Как веб сервер использую Nginx. Вот как делаю проксирование

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

Все работает. Но так как начала расти нагрузка, решил переехать на другой сервер, который использует SSD. Переехал, настроил, все как на старом сервере. И столкнулся с тем, что сайт стал грузиться еще дольше. Именно страница сайт

[image: скрин с браузера]

Подскажите, куда надо смотреть по поводу этой ошибки? Это nginx, или это NextJS? Может кто сталкивался